# Problem with vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

We have an equilateral triangle with side $a=1$, where $AD$ is height, how to find $\vec{AE}$ in terms of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ ? Where E is arbitrary point lying on the $AD$

[image: pic]

Comment: Do you know how to project vectors onto other vectors?

Comment: it looks the same as for lines ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you wish to express $AE$ as a sum of $AB$ and $AC$.  We can imagine $A$ being at the origin.  Then $B$ has coordinates $\langle 1,0\rangle$ and $C$ has coordinates $\langle\cos 60^\circ,\sin 60^\circ\rangle=\left\langle\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right\rangle$  Then you can project $AE=\langle x,y\rangle$ onto $\langle 1,0\rangle$ and onto $\left\langle\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right\rangle$ to get $AE$ as a sum
$$
AE =aAB+bBC.
$$

EDIT:  The midpoint between $B$ and $C$ is $\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)$.  Again, assuming $A$ is at the origin, the line through $A$ and $D$ is given by $\left(\frac{3}{4}t,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}t\right)$, with $0\leq t\leq 1$.

Comment: is it possible to express it by only one parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\triangle ABC$ equilateral with sides of length 1 and $A=(0,0)$, so $B=(1,0).$

As $AD$ is the height of $\triangle ABC$ the triangle $\triangle ADC$ is a right-angle triangle, applying Pythagoras's theorem we get $AC^2 = AD^2+DC^2 \Rightarrow 1 = AD^2 + (\frac{1}{2})^2 \Rightarrow AD = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

The distance from $D$ to the $X-axis$ equals $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ by the same reasoning above, so $D=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt3}{2}).$

Now denote by $t \in [0,\frac{\sqrt3}{2}]$ the distance of a point $P$ from $A$ on the segment $AD$, that is, for every $t \in [0,\frac{\sqrt3}{2}]$ we get a point $P$ on $AD$, when $t = 0$ we get $A$ and when $t = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ we get $D$.

Now for every point $P=(x,y)$ in $AD$ we get a right-angle triangle with hypotenuse $AP$ and sides $Ax$ and $Ay$, as $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral and $AD$ is the height $AP$ is a bisector of the angle, which divides it into two angles of $30^\circ$ each. Now we get:

$$\cos30^\circ = \frac{x}{t} \Rightarrow x = \cos30^\circ t \Rightarrow x =\frac{\sqrt3}{2}t$$
$$\sin30^\circ = \frac{y}{t} \Rightarrow y = \sin30^\circ t \Rightarrow y =\frac{1}{2}t$$

Now for every $t \in [0,\frac{\sqrt3}{2}]$ we get a point $P = (\frac{\sqrt3}{2}t,\frac{1}{2}t)$ in $AD$, which is the same as vector $\vec{AP}$.